# Combine iscroll.js with timesheet.js slideshow audio sync

Tags: javascript, audio, slideshow, synchronization, smil

I want to be able to use the swipe left/right functionality of iscroll.js into timesheet.js SMIL Timing slideshow engine with audio sync.

Swiping left or right advances slide/audio.

iscroll.js: http://cubiq.org/iscroll

timesheet.js audio sync demo: http://wam.inrialpes.fr/timesheets/slideshows/audio.html